# What is the right way to add apache-tika dependency into grails project

Tags: grails, apache-tika

When using tika-1.4 getting this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/core/DebuggingClassWriter
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Added these two lines into BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ("org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.4")
compile ("org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.4") {excludes "tika-core"}
```

If I don't exclude `tika-core` from `tika-parsers`, I'm getting 2 versions of `tika-core` (version 1.0 pulled by `vorbis-java-tika` dependency) and version `tika-core` version 1.4.

If I replace tika version to be 1.3, exception is gone.

**UPDATE 1**

This solution seems works:

```
compile ("org.apache.tika:tika-core:${tikaVersion}")
compile ("org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:${tikaVersion}") { excludes "tika-core", "commons-codec", "commons-logging", "slf4j-api" }
```

Comment: Run a `dependency-report` to see if there is discrepancy with any other artifact.

Comment: Already did it. No `cglib` or `asm` deps.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be the issue you're seeing -- we're working with tika 1.5 (snapshot).  That version pulls in asm-debug-all, which was the cause of our troubles (similar stacktrace to yours).  Try using 'asm-debug-all' in your tika-parsers excludes instead of 'tika-core'.

Comment: This made it compile, however I get a class not found error when attempting to actually use it